# Building subproject requiring installed files of another subproject with cmake

Tags: cmake

I wonder if it possible without any magic tricks to build in one super project two subprojects where one requires files from installation of another?

As an example: there is a `project A` which needs `file B` from `project B` which is generated at installation process. Both projects are cmake-based.

Real example: I've tried to build `kcoreaddons` together with `extra-cmake-modules` (both available [here](https://quickgit.kde.org/)). `kcoreaddons` requires however cmake files generated at installation step of `extra-cmake-modules`.

Is it possible? Any approach?

**EDIT**

Let me simplify it to go right to the point:

my project (let's call it `project X`) needs `project A` which needs to be installed before it can be used.

I've added `project A` with `ExternalProject_Add` with download, configure, build and install steps to my `project X`. The problem is my find script for `project A` cannot find it when I run `cmake` in a fresh clean build directory. That's obvious as `project A` will be built and installed at build step of `project X`. So if I make `project A` optional for `project X` then `project A` is installed and next time I run `cmake` for `project X`, `project A` is found.

Comment: What about using `ExternalProject_Add` for both projects, and then adjust dependency between targets?

Comment: @Tsyvarev that's what I've been thinking in first place. I didn't try it yet as I was wondering if there are other options. Still I'm not sure if there will be no problems even with this approach (like making `project A` depeding on installation of `project B`)

Comment: Please, be specific: Stack Overflow is *not a discussion* forum, but Q&A cite. `ExternalProject_Add` seems to be the most simple for your problem description. If you don't like it, say **why**. If it doesn't work for you, say **why**. These reasons will help in futher search for other approaches.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: so far I can see one problem: how do I write Find script for `project A`  in my superproject? It would require to run build & install of `project A` and `project B` at configration stage.

Comment: Hmm, isn't `project B` who should find `project A`? With `ExternalProject_Add` approach `project A` will be installed before `project B` begins configuring (all these steps will be doing at *build* stage of superproject).

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I've added more info

Comment: I mean that *super project* should use `ExternalProject_Add(X ...)`, `ExternalProject_Add(A ...)` and order them using `add_dependencies(X A)`.